# New endpoints not found [Angular Fullstack]

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, endpoint, angular-fullstack

I am using the Angular Fullstack to create a web application. I have a good number of custom endpoints created. All seem to work except this new endpoint I just created. I already tried reorganizing my endpoints, no new endpoints will work.

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./proctoring.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.create);
router.put('/:id', controller.upsert);
router.patch('/:id', controller.patch);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

// Custom routes
router.get('/activeexams/:id', controller.getAvailableExams);
router.get('/openexams/get', controller.getOpenExams);
router.get('/instructor/:id', controller.getInstructor);
router.get('/testsites/get', controller.getTestSites);
router.get('/courses/get', controller.getCourseList);
router.get('/timerestrictions/:id/:uid/:uuid', controller.getTimeRestrictions);
router.get('/fulldays/:id/:uid', controller.getFullDays);
router.get('/getexam/:id/:uid', controller.findExam);  // DOESNT WORK
router.post('/saveexam/', controller.saveExam);

router.get('/locations', controller.getTestSites);

module.exports = router;
```

Service that hits the endpoints

```
'use strict';
const angular = require('angular');

/*@ngInject*/
export function proctoringService($resource) {
  return $resource('api/proctorings/:controller/:id/:uid/:uuid', {
    id: '@_id'
  }, {
getAvailableExams: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'activeexams' }, isArray: true },
getOpenExams: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'openexams', id: 'get' } },
getCourseList: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'courses', id: 'get', }, isArray: true, },
getInstructor: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'instructor' } },
getTestSites: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'testsites', id: 'get' }, isArray: true },
getFullTimes: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'timerestrictions' }, isArray: true },
saveExam: { method: 'POST', params: { controller: 'saveexam' } },
getFullDays: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'fulldays' }, isArray: true },
getMyActiveExams: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'instructor', id: 'activeexams' }, isArray: true, },
findExam: { method: 'GET', params: { controller: 'getexam' } },
  });
}


export default angular.module('proctoringApp.proctoring', [])
  .factory('proctoring', proctoringService)
  .name;
```

Endpoint Controller:

```
'use strict';

import jsonpatch from 'fast-json-patch';
import {Proctoring, Exam, User, Testsite} from '../../sqldb';

function respondWithResult(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 200;
  return function(entity) {
    if(entity) {
      return res.status(statusCode).json(entity);
    }
    return null;
  };
}

function patchUpdates(patches) {
  return function(entity) {
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-reflect
      jsonpatch.apply(entity, patches, /*validate*/ true);
    } catch(err) {
      return Promise.reject(err);
    }
    return entity.save();
  };
}

function removeEntity(res) {
  return function(entity) {
    if(entity) {
      return entity.destroy()
        .then(() => {
          res.status(204).end();
        });
    }
  };
}

function handleEntityNotFound(res) {
  return function(entity) {
    if(!entity) {
      res.status(404).end();
      return null;
    }
    return entity;
  };
}

function handleError(res, statusCode) {
  statusCode = statusCode || 500;
  return function(err) {
    res.status(statusCode).send(err);
  };
}

// Gets a list of Proctorings
export function index(req, res) {
  return Proctoring.findAll()
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

// Gets a single Proctoring from the DB
export function show(req, res) {
  return Proctoring.find({
    where: {
       _id: req.params.id
    }
  })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

// Creates a new Proctoring in the DB
export function create(req, res) {
  return Proctoring.create(req.body)
    .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

// Upserts the given Proctoring in the DB at the specified ID
export function upsert(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) {
    Reflect.deleteProperty(req.body, '_id');
  }
  return Proctoring.upsert(req.body, {
    where: {
      _id: req.params.id
    }
  })
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

// Updates an existing Proctoring in the DB
export function patch(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) {
    Reflect.deleteProperty(req.body, '_id');
  }
  return Proctoring.find({
    where: {
      _id: req.params.id
    }
  })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(patchUpdates(req.body))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

// Deletes a Proctoring from the DB
export function destroy(req, res) {
  return Proctoring.find({
    where: {
      _id: req.params.id
    }
  })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(removeEntity(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

// Creates a new Exam in the DB
export function saveExam(req, res) {
  return Exam.create(req.body)
    .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

export function getAvailableExams(req, res) {
  let today = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate() + 7);
  today = today.toISOString();
  // Return tests that start date is less
  //than today and end date is greater than today
  return Exam.findAll({
    where: {
      course: req.params.id,
      enddate: {
        gte: today
      }
    }
  })
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

export function getOpenExams(req, res) {
  let today = new Date().toISOString();
  return Exam.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
      startdate: {
        lte: today
      },
      enddate: {
        gte: today
      }
    }
  })
  .then(respondWithResult(res))
  .catch(handleError(res));
}

export function getMyActiveExams(req, res) {
  let today = new Date().toISOString();
  return Exam.findAll({
    where: {
      uid: req.params.uid,
      startdate: {
        lte: today
      },
      enddate: {
        gte: today
      }
    }
  })
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

export function getTestSites(req, res) {
  return Testsite.findAll()
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

export function getInstructor(req, res) {
  return User.find({
    where: {
      _id: req.params.id
    }
  })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

export function getCourseList(req, res) {
  return Exam.findAll({
    attributes: ['course'],
    group: 'course'
  })
  .then(respondWithResult(res))
  .catch(handleError(res));
}

export function getFullDays(req, res) {
  return Proctoring.findAll({
    attributes: ['testdate'],
    where: {
      lid: req.params.id,
    },
    group: ['testdate', 'shift'],
    having: ['count(*) >= ' + req.params.uid],
  })
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

export function getTimeRestrictions(req, res) {
  let D = new Date(req.params.uuid).toISOString();
  // DONE: Get restricted times for given day selected
  return Proctoring.findAll({
    attributes: ['shift'],
    where: {
      lid: req.params.id,
      testdate: D
    },
    group: ['shift'],
    having: ['count(*) >=' + req.params.uid],
  })
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

export function findExam(req, res) {
  return Proctoring.find({
    where: {
      uid: req.params.id,
      eid: req.params.uid,
    }
  })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

When I try to access all my other endpoints with either the browser or postman, they return as they should. When I try to add even any new simple endpoints, they are not found.

I don't know if there is some sort of limit as to how many endpoints you can have; there shouldn't be.

Anyone have any ideas? I receive an error 404.

Comment: I see no problems with your routes. Please post your controller code.

Comment: Updated with controller as well as service used to access endpoints on client side.

Comment: No new endpoints work at all, no matter where in the routing declarations they appear? Please log `req` and `res` in `findExam()` and report back.

Comment: It's ok. I got it to work. I literally deleted the endpoint, remade it, and copy pasted the code. Rebuilt the project and now they work. Really weird.